# How to import all data of products for WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, data-import

Either when we use WooCommerce or ShopEngine Plugin with WordPress, I am confused to import product data such as title, price and short description. But only title, image and price are imported from products and other parameters are not imported.

[image]

[image]

[image]

How to solve this problem.
I wish help of this problem.

Comment: Woo importer will import everything default to woo. Any custom data will be ignored. Use plugin like WP All Import where you can map each field etc.